# Original proof of Taylor's theorem

Tags: math-history, taylor-expansion

There are numerous proofs for Taylor's theorem,
but

What's the original proof for Taylor's theorem (by Taylor?)?

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem) it says:

> Taylor's theorem is named after the mathematician Brook Taylor, who
>   stated a version of it in 1712. Yet an explicit expression of the
>   error was not provided until much later on by Joseph-Louis Lagrange.
>   An earlier version of the result was already mentioned in 1671 by
>   James Gregory.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem)

So if Taylor's was incomplete (or was it?), then what was the first "complete" one?

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The answer to your question is right there in the quote: Lagrange.

Comment: For Taylor's derivation of the Taylor series see: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/491405